# Reading .xls-file in R

Tags: r, excel, xlsx, readxl, openxlsx

I am trying to read a .xls-file into a R dataframe. I've tried:

```
library(readxl)
dfTest <- readxl::read_excel("file_path/file.xls")
```

Which gives me:

```
Error: 
filepath: file_path/file.xls
libxls error: Unable to open file
```

Next I tried:

```
library(xlsx)
dfTest <- xlsx::read.xlsx("file_path/file.xls",1)
```

Which results in:

```
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.io.IOException: block[ 1462 ] already removed - does your POIFS have circular or duplicate block references?
```

I tried:

```
library(openxlsx)
dfTest <- openxlsx::read.xlsx("file_path/file.xls")
```

Which results in:

```
Error in read.xlsx.default("file_path/file.xls") : 
  openxlsx can not read .xls or .xlm files!
```

Last thing that I tried was:

```
library(RODBC)
conn <- odbcConnectExcel("file_path/file.xls")
```

Which gives me:

```
Error in odbcConnectExcel("file_path/file.xls") : 
  odbcConnectExcel is only usable with 32-bit Windows
```

Would anyone have an idea how I can read the Excel file? Saving the file as .csv-file and loading it into R works perfectly fine. However, I have a large amount of files that I ultimately want to read and process in a loop. Saving all by hand as .csv is teadious to say the least.
I'm restricted in changing the software installations on the computer I'm working on.

Comment: This is somewhat a shot in the dark, but have you tried using `odbcConnectExcel` with 32-bit R? I know I had to do this when connecting to a 32-bit MS Access database with RODBC.

Comment: I thought about that but is there a way to use 32-bit R without changing my installation? I don't have admin rights on the computer I am working on...

Comment: As long as it's installed (which I think the default R installation installs both 32 and 64 bit versions), you should be able to. I was able to do this on my work computer where I'm in the same situation. In the case of RStudio, Tools -> Global Options -> General should allow you to switch which version is being used. You'll have to restart RStudio fo this to take effect (and switch it back later). I used this approach for development, then switched to a batch file which then I just specified the path to the 32-bit Rscript executable `C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.0\bin\i386\Rscript myScript.R`

Comment: Does not work for me unfortunately. I have only the 64 bit version installed without 32 bit version and I cannot change the installation easily/fast (work computer). I re-solved the issue by using a macro in VBA that converst all of the .xls files into .csv files. The .csv files read into R without a problem. I leave the question open anyways. Maybe someone has an idea and maybe this will be useful for others. I guess there is something odd going on with the encoding of the .xls files...

Answer (score 0):

I believe for .xls files read_delim from the readr package should work.

For example:

```
readr::read_delim("file_path/file.xls",as.is=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, that does something (btw, read.delim is not from readr but utils). I get the warning message `Warning message:
In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on "file_path/file.xls"` The resulting dataframe has 0 rows and a single column with a non-sensical name. Do you know what is meant by the warning?

Comment: apologies, see my edit; function should be 'read_delim'. that works for me for .xls files. any better?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It reads something but not really the file contents. It creates a dataframe with a few thousend rows and one column. Col name is non-sensical symbols, rows are empty. I think the issue is the argument for delim that I have to specify. I tried "\t" for tab and " " for whitespace but neither is working.

Comment: Are you able to share the .xls file or create a reproducible example that causes the error?

Comment: No, I can't share the file(s). Sorry. As for a reproducible example, I did succesfully read other .xls files with read_excel. Any example I tried to create manually does not reproduce the issue. The files I'm trying to read are not manually generated. For some reason R has issues only those particular .xls files. However, they open in Excel itself without problem, so they don't seem to be corrupted in some way. Could there be a problem with the encoding of the files?